# Is it possible to list SpatialGridDataFrame files to be used in a loop?

Tags: raster, spatial-database, stack, for-loop

I have a lot (>50) of SpatialGridDataFrame files that I need to turn into raster files, stack with a set of raster files I already have and then extract data from random points from each layer of all of these individual stacks. I have written the code to do this for each file at a time and it works fine but I was trying to use a loop so I could run this for all of the SpatialGridDataFrame files in one go rather than one at a time.

I wasn't successful at listing the SpatialGridDataFrame files together to use as an input into the loop and get the following (example just with a few of my original files);

```
Layer1 <- list(SpatialGridDataFrame1A,SpatialGridDataFrame2A,SpatialGridDataFrame3A,SpatialGridDataFrame4A)))
Layer2 <- list(SpatialGridDataFrame1B,SpatialGridDataFrame2B,SpatialGridDataFrame3B,SpatialGridDataFrame4B)))
```

But this doesn't work correctly and when I try to call up the lists they look like this;

```
> Layer1
[[1]]
class       : SpatialGridDataFrame 
dimensions  : 11, 44, 484, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.01788854, 0.01788854  (x, y)
Error in .printSpatial(x) : object 'nf' not found
```

Is there a way of listing these files together successfully so that I can then run the following loop?

```
for (i in 1:4)
 {
  L1 <- raster(Layer1[i])
  L2 <- raster(Layer2[i])
  depth <- raster(Depth_int)

rasterratio<- (L1/L2)

stack_all <- stack(L1,L2,depth,rasterratio)
assign( paste("layers",i,sep="_"), stack_all) 
}
```

Or maybe use some other function like lapply to achieve this?